# Android preferences when application only contains service

Tags: android, service, preferences

I have a app that only consists of 2 services and a broadcast receiver (they check the internet periodically). I need to store preferences that can be shared across those services. Is this the same as for an activity? Just use getsharedpreferences()? This doesn't seem to be documented very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, just `getSharedDefaultPreferences` or `getSharedPreferences`.  Use them the exact same way you would with an Activity.